# strange error iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios4

So I have a table view that contains a bunch of data.  The user can navigate down, browse edit, etc.  However when they edit and delete a row, and then navigate back via the nav controller, sometimes (not all the time) the app crashes throwing this error:

```
-[CALayer resourceType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance: **********
```

does anyone know what could be causing this error?  I can't seem to isolate the cases where this happens, it seems random.  The data for this is coming from an array.  Not sure if that makes a difference.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Must likely, you are over-releasing an object or releasing an object too soon (or not retaining an object).

Turn on zombie detection and try to reproduce the crash.  (Instruments has a zombie detection mode or search Google for NSZombieEnabled).

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html

Comment: Yeah it's a problem with my NSDocumentController causing a memoryWarning which releases stuff that shouldn't be yet. (everything that I read online said it needs to be retained).  I guess the question is now, when exactly should I be releasing the docCOntroller??

Comment: Figured it out.  The zombie mode was really helpful.  Thanks!